# What determines valid cipher in SSL/TLS exchange?

Tags: tomcat, ssl, x509certificate

I am in a situation where I have to remove ciphers from tomcat, and currently only have the 3 ciphers below.

```
 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
 SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

Now I am asked to remove SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA and when I do, I cannot connect to the server anymore via a browser (no cipher overlap) or via openssl s_client

I have read elsewhere that part of the client/server hello interaction depends on the server certificate as well.

In my case, the server certificate have the following properties (see below).

Do I need a new certificate in order to support the RSA_WITH_AES ciphers ?

Thanks

Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption

```
Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption      
RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
```

X509v3 extensions:

```
X509v3 Key Usage: critical             
Digital Signature, Key Encipherment         
X509v3 Extended Key Usage:            
TLS Web Server Authentication
```

Comment: You are confusing key-exchange, authentication, and bulk-encryption. The key-exchange and authentication algorithms in your examples above are both using RSA, which has been all-but-deprecated for key-exchange due to its lack of forward-secrecy and replaced by DHE or ECDHE. RSA is still okay to use for authentication (certificate-checking), while EC certificates are becoming more popular. Everything after the `_WITH_` in the cipher suite (the ""bulk encryption") is not dependent upon the type of key-exchange or authentication performed during the TLS handshake.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the naming of the cipher.
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA is not valid for my JRE while 
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, is valid.

So just changing the TLS_ to SSL_ should fix the issue.

Comment: Try running `SSLContext.getSocketFactory().getSupportedCipherSuites()` on your JVM next time and print-out the cipher suites you get. If you are using OpenSSL as your underlying SSL library, the cipher suite names are different. Recent versions of Tomcat can accept either variety of cipher suite specification.